# My dplyr code not working all of a sudden

Tags: r

My code is the one shown below:

```
  New_promo_store%>%
  mutate(MiniTotal = rowSums(.[4:17], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(`ITEM#`) %>%
  mutate(Total = sum(MiniTotal, na.rm = TRUE))
```

However, instead of adding per ITEM#, it's adding the whole column together

[image]

This code was working fine just last week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the package `plyr` was also loaded along with `dplyr` and the `mutate` from `plyr`masked the other `mutate`.  An option is to specify `dplyr::` or do this on a fresh `R` session with only `dplyr` loaded

```
library(dplyr)
New_promo_store%>%
   dplyr::mutate(MiniTotal = rowSums(.[4:17], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    group_by(`ITEM#`) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Total = sum(MiniTotal, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I have found many instances where `plyr` has no business being loaded, as well. You (Piccinin1992) might investigate if you are actually using `plyr` in your code; if not, there should be no need to load it (therefore preempting this problem from the start).

Comment: Worked, thanks r2evans and akrun. Forgot that package was loaded in as well.